# Do I need to have an additional validation for a BigDecimal to check if it is a number and not any string in Java?

Tags: java, string, validation, bigdecimal

I'm working on a Rest API in Java and Spring Boot and I have a POST request and it contains a request body, an object RequestCustomer and one of the field is of type BigDecimal. I need to do a regex for this variable to accept only numbers, not any other value like for example "abcd", it should accept only numbers like 100, 75.30, these values represents money. And this variable is of type BigDecimal and I can't change this variable type.

I want to use the @Pattern annotation from javax.validation.constraints like this:

```
@Pattern(
   regexp = "..."
)

@NotNull
private BigDecimal value;
```

If the variable is of type BigDecimal, do I need to have an additional validation to check if it is a number and not any string? If yes, what regex should I use for that variable to accept only numbers? Any feedback will be apreciated!

Comment: Why do you think that `BigDecimal`, which is a **number**, can be any random string like `abcd`?

Answer (score 1):

*BigDecimal* is a number, but it could be 45.465468494456156.

If you want to restrict the number of decimal places, you will need to define your own validation. [*@Pattern*](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) won't do it because it accepts instances of *CharSequence*.

There is a *java.util.Currency* that might be useful, but perhaps you will need to handle serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal is a number by definition and can't be a string . Running the code below will give you `java.lang.NumberFormatException` :

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    
    BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal("abcd");
  
 }
}
```

About decimal places you could use ROUND

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("10.12345");

a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```